# onItemClickListener stops working after changing visibility of item child

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout /* not important */>

    <TextView /* not important */ />

    <TextView /* not important */ />

    <RelativeLayout
        /* not important */ 
        android:id="@+id/detailLayout"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView /* not important */ />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

.

```
private class ItemClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        RelativeLayout detailLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.detailLayout);
        int detailLayoutVisibility = detailLayout.getVisibility();

        if(detailLayoutVisibility == View.GONE)
        {
            detailLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            detailLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

First when I click the item, the event fires and `detailLayout` changes visibility to `View.VISIBLE`, but then any further attempt to click it results in no event firing.

Comment: why use `ItemClickListener `?  where did you use `ItemClickListener ` . Mention what components your setting `ItemClickListener `

Comment: How do you call ItemClickListener? 

Please try to set android:clickable="true" for main RelativeLayout

Comment: can you try invisible instead of gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, create a global variable for your `detailLayout` instead of initializing it every time you click. Then in your `onCreate` set the click listener of `detailLayout` to `this` since you implemented the `onClickListener`.

Also, why did you implement `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` instead of `View.OnClickListener`? You want to click a `RelativeLayout` not adapter right?

Instead of just setting the visibility of `detailLayout` to `GONE`, try also to do the same with the child views of `detailLayout`, i.e. set the visibility of the `TextView` inside the `detailLayout` to `GONE`.

Answer (score 1):

try setting your detailLayout to

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

also, the stuff you say is unimportant, could very well be quite important.

Comment: I believe, `layout_width` and `layout_height` settings hardly affect this behavior, setting `clickable` to `false` doesn't help as well